# Uploading app to google play store and encryption of firebase real time data base

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-play

Firebase documents states that (please check the link [enter link description here](https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy#:%7E:text=Security%20information-,Data%20encryption,Cloud%20Firestore) last part of document states that Firebase services encrypt data in transit using HTTPS and logically isolate customer data.) I had completed an app in android studio using firebase real time database. I was trying to upload app in google play store through google developer play console. In google play console they are asking whether app is encrypted in transit or not? It is a closed question and we have to select either yes or no.
I have a doubt in answering this question, I didn't done anything in my app to encrypt data in transit or wrote any code in my app to do so, but I am using firebase services. In this case which answer will be more appropriate yes or no?

Answer (score 1):

"Encrypted in transit" means network connections that transfer data are encrypted.  This includes connections to web sites and APIs, including Firebase services.

All Firebase services using secure (encrypted) connections.  You can read about that in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy#security_information):

> Firebase services encrypt data in transit using HTTPS and logically isolate customer data.

This means that data is encrypted in transit when using Firebase SDKs and services. HTTPS is always secure as long as the certificate is issued by a reputable authority.

Whether or not other components of your app also do the same, I don't know.  But Firebase services are OK.